# Snapping a window vertically makes it expand up both monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, aero-snap

I have two 1920x1080 monitors arranged on top of each other.

[image]

When I snap a window that is in the bottom monitor to the bottom edge of that monitor, it expands so the window takes all the way from the bottom edge of the bottom monitor to the top edge of the top monitor (shown in red). I would expect the window to just expand between the top and bottom edges of the bottom monitor (shown in green).

[image]

Is there a way to "fix" this behavior?

Here is what I mean by snapping the window to the bottom (Screenshot is in Win7 with just one monitor, though I'm asking about Win8.1):
[image: http://i.imgur.com/cpMUGz3.png]

Also, `Win-Shift-Up` accomplishes the same thing as snapping.

Comment: In Charms bar, did you go to > Devices > Project > Extend? Or did you choose a different option?

Comment: @user-12506 I right clicked on my Desktop and used the "Screen Resolution" option to arrange my monitors. I'll edit the question to show a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this can be done on system level, but below is a working script using AutoHotKey to achieve this. Press Shift+Win+Up to activate. Of course you can assign to other hotkeys.

The code was heavily modified from the SO answer by Jeff Axelrod in [How can I maximize a window across multiple monitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17920847/1163085).

```
+#Up::
  WinGetActiveTitle, Title
  WinRestore, %Title%
  ActiveMonitor := GetCurrentMonitor()
  SysGet, MaxArea, MonitorWorkArea, %ActiveMonitor%
  WinMove, %Title%, , , MaxAreaTop, , MaxAreaBottom - MaxAreaTop
return

GetCurrentMonitor()
{
  SysGet, numberOfMonitors, MonitorCount
  WinGetPos, winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight, A
  winMidX := winX + winWidth / 2
  winMidY := winY + winHeight / 2
  Loop %numberOfMonitors%
  {
    SysGet, monArea, Monitor, %A_Index%
    if (winMidX > monAreaLeft && winMidX < monAreaRight && winMidY < monAreaBottom && winMidY > monAreaTop) {
      return A_Index
    }
  }
  SysGet, primaryMonitor, MonitorPrimary
  return "No Monitor Found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming desktop, not modern UI (metro) mode. Do you want to turn off Snap or just make snap only fill one screen. Try dragging it to the top of the bottom screen instead of the bottom/bottom so it snaps down.

Comment: Dragging the whole window to the top of the screen fills the top monitor. There is no way to do that for the bottom monitor. Resizing the window (as per my screenshot) to the top has the same behavior as resizing to the bottom, the height is snapped to span across both monitors.

Comment: try using the Windows Key + Page Up (or Page Down)

Comment: Also what video card(s) are you using. Check the driver versions and if there's reports of issues for those.